# not able to print value inside angular scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I've written a code in Node.js for back-end and HTML code for the front end.
The value passed by the Node.js code is not getting printed on the html web page.

The Node.js code is :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var googlePlaySearch = require('google-play-search');
var templateData = "";
var path = require ('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '.../public')));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname+'/app');
app.set('view engine', 'dot');
app.use('/css',express.static(__dirname+'/public/css'));
app.use('/img',express.static(__dirname+'/public/img'));
app.use('/js',express.static(__dirname+'/public/js'));
var templateData1 = "";

app.get('/index.htm', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
});

app.get('/process_get', function (req, res) {
  first_name:req.query.first_name
  googlePlaySearch.fetch(req.query.first_name, function(err, response) {
    console.log(response.categories);
    templateData = response.categories ;
  });
  var thisObject = {templateData1 : templateData}
  res.render(__dirname + "/" + "out.html", thisObject);
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port
  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

The `index.html` source code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>yo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><marquee style="color:yellow">this is a page to find app details..</marquee></h1>
    <center>
      <table> 
        <tr>
          <form id="f1" action="/process_get" method="GET">
            <h3 style="color:red">Package Name</h3>:<br>
            <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="font-size: 20px">
          </form>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the `out.html` (template) code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
      <form id="f1" method="POST">
        <table>
          <tr style="border: 1px solid black">
            <td style="border: 1px solid black">
              <h1>: {{thisObject.categories}}! </h1>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

The output is printing the `": !"` and not the value inbetween those symbols.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use Angular, but I don't see the code for initializing an angular module and controller.

Comment: This won't work, you're misunderstanding the difference between serverside javascript and client-side javascript. You can't declare a variable 'thisObject' on your server and have it in your web browser like this. Check for basics tutorials on the net about node.js and angular.js

Comment: @OzW can you tell me how to initialize angular js module and controller as i'm new to angular .

Comment: I recommend starting with the [guides on AngularJS site](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started).